# Ganglia client won't report metrics to server on 64bit CentOS

Tags: centos, 64-bit, ganglia

I have Ganglia server on Ubuntu and Ganglia client (gmond) on CentOS client. The metrics for client machine don't appear on UI

When I try to restart the gmond service on client, I get errors:

```
service gmond restart
Shutting down GANGLIA gmond:                               [  OK  ]
Starting GANGLIA gmond: Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/modcpu.so metric module:     /usr/lib/ganglia/modcpu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/moddisk.so metric module: /usr/lib/ganglia/moddisk.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/modload.so metric module: /usr/lib/ganglia/modload.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/modmem.so metric module: /usr/lib/ganglia/modmem.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/modnet.so metric module: /usr/lib/ganglia/modnet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/modproc.so metric module: /usr/lib/ganglia/modproc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load /usr/lib/ganglia/modsys.so metric module: /usr/lib/ganglia/modsys.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Also the /var/log/messages would report:

```
/usr/sbin/gmond[6374]: Unable to find the metric information for 'pkts_in'. Possible that the module has not been loaded.#012
```

Answer (score 1):

On a 64 bit machine, the path to .so files mentioned in error message should be `/usr/lib64/ganglia/` so a file which it complains can't find at `/usr/lib/ganglia/modcpu.so` is actually at `/usr/lib64/ganglia/modcpu.so`.

The configuration of these module paths is in `/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf` as also [documented here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/Gmond%203.1%20configuration). Modify paths in the file and restart gmond service on client and you are good.